# Problems with Char type and switch case

Tags: c++, function, char, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a calculator with functions, and I use the symbols `'+'` `'-'` `'/'` `'*'` to select the operations, and `'x'` to close the program. If I insert any other value, the program will ask to  insert again. But if I insert `N` (multiples, maybe for a misclick) number of characters, the `switch` case will be executed `N` times.

Here is an example. As you can see, the input is `'awd'` and the `switch` has been executed with the `'a'` the `'w'` and the `'d'`:

[image]

Can you help me to resolve this? I want that in these cases, the `switch` will be executed one time.

I have no idea on how to resolve it.

Something is written in Italian, but the important things are written in English.

This is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float somma(float a, float b);
float sottrazione(float a,float b);
float moltiplicazione(float a,float b);
float divisione(float a,float b);

int main(){
    
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"ita");
    
    float a,b;
    char o,s;
    
    cout << "*******************************Calcolatrice*******************************" << endl;
    
    do{
        s = 0;
        
         cout << "Enter the symbol corresponding to the operation you want to perform:" << endl << "'+' somma" << endl;
         cout << "'-' sottrazione " << endl <<"'*' moltiplicazione " << endl << "'/' divisione " << endl << "'x' per chiudere il programma " << endl;
            cin >> s;

         cout << " S: " << s << endl;
         
         switch(s){
            
         case '+':
         cout << "Inserire il numero 1: ";
         cin >> a;
         cout << "Inserire il numero 2: ";
         cin >> b;
         somma(a,b);
         break;
         
         case '-':
         cout << "Inserire il numero 1: ";
         cin >> a;
         cout << "Inserire il numero 2: ";
         cin >> b;  
         sottrazione(a,b);
         break;
         
         case '*':
         cout << "Inserire il numero 1: ";
         cin >> a;
         cout << "Inserire il numero 2: ";
         cin >> b;
         moltiplicazione(a,b);
         break;
         
         case '/':
         cout << "Inserire il numero 1: ";
         cin >> a;
         cout << "Inserire il numero 2: ";
         cin >> b;
         divisione(a,b);
         break;
         
         case 'x':
         case 'X':
         break;
         
         default: 
         cout << "No operator has been chosen. Try again!";
         s = 0;
         break;
       }
       cout << endl << endl;
    }while(s != 'x' && s!= 'X');
    cout << "**************************************************************************";
         
return 0;
}

float somma(float a, float b){
    float x = a+b;
    cout << x;
    return x;
}

float sottrazione(float a, float b){
    float x = a-b;
    cout << x;
    return x;
}

float moltiplicazione(float a, float b){
    float x = a*b;
    cout << x;
    return x;
}

float divisione(float a, float b){
    float x = a/b;
    cout << x;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: If you enter multiple non-digit characters, e.g. `cin >> a` will fail. The state of `std::cin` will have a flag set that means you can't read from it again. This is why I recommend you read whole lines into a string, and then try to convert the string contents to the data you need.

Comment: With that said, you can *clear* the flag, and ask `std::cin` to *ignore* the rest of the line if that happens. But you need to actually check if the input operation fails or not.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of data.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: *"I want that in these case the switch will be executed one time"* -- Could you be more precise? To have the switch executed literally one time, remove the loop. To have the switch executed once per character, keep what you have. You seem to want something in between. Do you want once per pressing of `Enter` (a.k.a. once per line of input)?

Comment: Keep in mind that a [mre] should demonstrate the problem, not "a calculator with functions". Skip unneeded I/O and unneeded processing. Try something more like (with better formatting) `int main(){
char s;
do{
s = 0;
cout << "Enter awd:\n";
cin >> s;
cout << " S: " << s << endl;
switch(s){
case '+':
cout << "Add\n";
break;

case '-':
cout << "Subtract\n";
break;

case '*':
cout << "Multiply\n";
break;

case '/':
cout << "Divide\n";
break;

case 'x':
case 'X':
cout << "Exit\n";
break;

default: 
cout << "Default case";
break;
}
}while(s != 'x' && s!= 'X');
}`

Comment: Things I did in my previous comment: Remove the "Calcolatrice" intro and the closing line. Reduce the instructions to "Enter awd:" (since that is how to reproduce the error). Reduce each case to a single line of output to indicate the case was executed. It's basically all that is needed to get input then demonstrate that the `switch` statement is executed multiple times. Actually, you don't really need the `switch` either, but that's the next step as you simplify your example code.

Answer (score 3):

I'd probably add a small function like:

```cpp
char read_one_of(std::string_view choices);`
```

The reads input characters until it gets one of the choices that was passed to it, so you'd call it like:

```cpp
s = read_one_of("+-/*x");

switch (s) { 
    // ...
```

This way, by the time you execute the `switch`, you know the character you're getting is valid.

Comment: thank you, but i'd like to solve problem in another way. I'd like also to know why that happens

Comment: @GianlucaMennella: It's doing what you told it to. In other words, it happens because that's what your code said should happen.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `s` to be a `char`, so `cin >> s` will read in a single character only, leaving any remaining characters in the input buffer for later reading.

Since you are entering 3 characters of input, and reading 1 character at a time inside of a loop, you end up with 3 separate inputs in `s`.  This is perfectly normal and expected behavior.

To do what you are asking for, read from `std::cin` into a `std::string` instead, and then validate that `string::size()` is `1` before `switch`'ing on its 1st character, eg:

```
string input;
char s;
    
...

do{    
    s = 0;

    cout << "Enter the symbol corresponding to the operation you want to perform:" << endl << "'+' somma" << endl;
    cout << "'-' sottrazione " << endl <<"'*' moltiplicazione " << endl << "'/' divisione " << endl << "'x' per chiudere il programma " << endl;

    if (!(cin >> input))
        break;

    // or:
    // if (!getline(cin, input))
    //     break; 

    if (input.size() != 1) {
        cout << "bad input, try again" << endl;
        continue;
    }

    s = input[0];
    cout << " S: " << s << endl;
         
    switch(s){
        ...
```